Part not moving with Motor6D object
I'm trying to make an animation where the player attacks with a string.
The string object (Plane) gets copied from ReplicatedStorage.
I need to position the string where the right hand of the player is, add a Motor6D object so the animation works, and then plays the animation.
However, when I try to do that, the string just gets stuck in the player's neck or the wrong position.
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)

    wait(1)

    local Weapon = game.ReplicatedStorage.Weapon:Clone()
    Weapon.Parent = workspace
    Weapon.Position = Vector3.new(5,5,5)
    
    local primaryPart = plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart
    local hand = plr.Character.RightHand
    
    wait(1)
    
    local motor = Instance.new("Motor6D")
    motor.Part0 = hand
    motor.Part1 = Weapon
    motor.Parent = Weapon

end)

I tried removing the Motor6D, it worked, but the animation didn't work. I tried setting the string parent to workspace, but it also didn't work after I added the Motor6D object. Part0 is the right hand of the user, Part1 is the string.
I expected the string to position itself correctly.
